# With MicrosoftGraph SDK how do you add extension property to user

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

There is a huge problem with documentation for Microsoft Graph where only set up of initial project is described. Where could I check documentation with examples of how to use Microsoft Graph SDK for example for adding extension property to user or group?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Microsoft provides two ways to add custom data to resources using extensions, **open extensions** and **schema extensions**.

> Open extensions is the recommended solution for most scenarios involving storing and accessing custom data. If, however, you need to access custom data for Outlook MAPI properties that are not already exposed through the Microsoft Graph API metadata, you can use extended properties and its REST API. You can verify which properties the metadata exposes at https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata.

More detail about the difference about these two scenarios you can refer [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_open_users).

And based on the test, I am not able to find the corresponding method for create an open extensions or sechma extensions using the latest version of Microsoft Graph SDK. I suggest that you using the REST as a workaround. And for the detailed of request, you can follow the links below:

[Add custom data to users using open extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_open_users)

[Add custom data to groups using schema extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_schema_groups)

Answer (score 0):

We are busy adding open and schema extension functionality to the SDKs, and we'll come back to this thread when the SDKs are updated.  You can also find SDK info and instructions and basic documentation from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks).  In general we only fully document our REST APIs - the SDKs follow a very similar addressing pattern to the REST APIs, and individual SDK documentation may call out particular scenarios like how to page through collections using the SDK.

We'd love to hear more from you on your documentation and SDK requirements, if this doesn't meet your needs.

(Also please ignore the highlighted text in the last answer - this text needs to be fixed and is more targeted to the Outlook resources like messages and events.)

Hope this helps,

Comment: 1.4.0 seems to be live now with support for adding and managing schema extensions! Thanks. What should also be provided is an example of how to enrich OOTB entities with schema extensions. E.g. how to read and write Group entities that encompass a schema extension?

Comment: Agreed and thanks for updating the thread Carl.  There are some examples for schema extensions in Graph Explorer - we'll add more as we relax some constraints that prevent schema extension definition management in Graph Explorer.  Not sure if this is what you are looking for.  We should also provide an update to the snippets sample to consume the updated client library.